# Panel Bootstrap collapse - Displays incorrectly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Please check code:

**JSFiddle:** [`Here`](https://jsfiddle.net/2z4ncp4u/7/)

**CSS:**

```
.panel-heading a:after {
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content:"\e114";
    float: right;
    color: grey;
}
.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
    content:"\e080";
}
```

**Problem (Image):**

[image]

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `class="collapsed"` on your first `<a>` Tag

Comment: True, I really forgot. Thank you for your answer.